# Is it possible to use Spring without a configuration file?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, annotations

In my unit tests I want to configure Spring in code (API, Annotations) so they will not depend on bean configuration files.

Can this be done?

For example:

```
Class Dependency {}

Class A
{
    @AutoWired
    Dependency d;
}
```

When testing A, I want to be able to create an instance of it with the Dependency member resolved, without having to use configuration files.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes, you can start a spring application context with any of the implementations of [org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html). Namely, if you don't want to load the definitions from an XML file, you can use the [org.springframework.context.support.StaticApplicationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/StaticApplicationContext.html) or [org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/GenericApplicationContext.html) to start the context.

With the context instantiated, you can start creating beans with the BeanFactory, either the oen default to the selected context or a custom one, that suits your needs.

In practice, it's lot more work than that. It's easier if you just use plain XML configuration, but it can be done.

Comment: Thanks! This sounds promising. 
How can I tell my JUnit test to use this context?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Java configuration](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-springjava/index.html) instead of the XML configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AnnotationConfigApplicationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.html) to create application context programatically without bean configuration files.